# How do you convert a hash of things to params to be sent to a method in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to call a method that takes n number of arguments, and the arguments are passed in as a hash to the method that calls the method with n arguments, but a hash just looks like another paramater. How do I unhash my parameter so the method gets called correctly?

Some code, cause this is hard to explain with just words:

the method I want to call: 
`method(p[:method]).call(p[:action], p[:params])`
`p[:method]` in this case is `:post`
`p[:action]` is `:create`
`p[:params]` is `{:my_object => {my object's params}}`

so, unravelled, it looks like this:
`post(:create, {:my_object => {my object's params}})`  # current
but what it should look like, is this:
`post(:create, :my_object => {my object's params})`   # desired

---

How do I change 
`method(p[:method]).call(p[:action], p[:params])` such that I can get the desired method call?

Comment: your current and desired constructions are just the same

Answer (score 1):

Actually

```
post(:create, {:my_object => {my object's params}})
```

and

```
post(:create, :my_object => {my object's params})
```

are the same constructions.

In both cases you will path two attributes to method `post`: symbol `:create` and a hash.

Anyway, you can do this ugly trick, in case if you have got only one key in `params`:

```
method(p[:method]).call(p[:action], p[:params].keys.first => p[:params].values.first)
```